# Latex Command for Greatest Integer Function

Tags: keycommand

I tried browsing and cant fnd the command for the double bracket symbol found below:

[image]

Comment: You can use http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html for that

Comment: You have the pairs `\llbracket ...`rrbracket` in `srmaryrd` or `\ldbrack ... `rdbrack` in `mathbx`. However, the correct notation is `\floor ... rfloor`. This one is usually to denote an integers interval.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for pointing out mathbx package. But it should be mathabx and this fix the problem

Comment: Note that if  you use the standard fonts for maths, you can use glyphs from `mathabx` without replacing the whole set of maths fonts.